# Understanding One Class SVM decision function output

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a one class classification problem that I have used a One Class SVM on. I printed out the decision function data and here is what I get :

```
[[ -3.37130521e+10]
 [  5.90432823e+13]
 [  4.73564603e+13]
 ..., 
 [  4.08249382e+11]
 [  4.68541816e+12]
 [  4.03591773e+11]]
```

How do I make sense of this? What do these rather huge numbers mean?

Answer (score 1):

These are the distances of your samples to the separating hyperplane learned by the model. The `predict` method uses these by interpreting a postitive distance as `+1` and a negative distance as `-1`.

Comment: +1: when the test sample is inside the one-class boundary. -1: when the test sample is outside the one-class boundary.